# Magento2.3.2: Undefined quantity on product saving

Tags: product, magento2.3.2, undefined

I just tried to save the product, Then I[image] am seeing one error at product section.

> **Notice:** Undefined index: quantity in /home/my_username/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/GetProductSalableQty.php
>   on line 83

I ran indexer command also. But same error.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Did already. But same error

Comment: Go to Product attribute, open Quantity attribute and save it after this run indexer.